# Understanding Verilog Code with two Clocks

Tags: verilog

I am pretty new to Verilog
and I use it to verify some code from a simulation program.
Right now I am struggeling if a verilog code snippet because the simulation programm uses 2 clocks ( one system clock and a pll of this ) where two hardware componentes work together, thus synchronize each other:

```
module something (input data)
reg vid;
always @(posegde sys_clk)
  vid <= data;

always @(posegde pll_clk)
  if (vid)
    // do something
```

When reading about non blocking assignments it says the evaluation of the left-hand side is postponed until other evaluations in the current time step are completed.

Intuitive I thought this means they are evaluated at the end of the time step, thus if data changes from 0 to 1 in sys_clk tick "A", this means at the end of "A" and the beginning of next sys_clk tick this value is in vid and so only after "A" the second always block ( of pll_clk) can read vid = 1

Is this how it works or did i miss something ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case it means that

1. if posedge *sys_clk* and *pll_clk* happen simultaneously then *vid* will not have a chance to update before it gets used in the *pll_clk* block. So, if vid was '0' before the clock edges (and is updated to '1' in the first block), it will still be '0' in the *if* statement of the second block. This sequence is guaranteed by use of the non-blocking assignment in the first block
2. if the posedges are not happening at the same time, then the value of *vid* will be updated at posedge sys_clk and picked up later at the following posedge of *pll_clk*.

In simulation non-blocking assignment guarantees that the assignment itself happens **after** all the blocks are evaluated in the current clock tick. It has nothing to do with the next clock cycle. However, the latter is often  used in tutorials to illustrate a particular single-clock situation, creating confusion.

Also being simultaneous is a simulation abstraction, meaning that both edges happen in the same clock tick (or within a certain small time interval in hardware).

Comment: Ahh okey so this means, for all the pll_clk ticks that happens later than sys_clk I can assume the value is updated already? Thank you for the answer